# How to implement a genetic algorithm with distance, time, and cost

Tags: java, algorithms, genetic-algorithms

I want to make a solution to find the optimum route of school visit. For example, I want to visit 5 schools (A, B, C, D, E) in my city. Given the choice of five routes regarding what school I should visit first, then the second, then the third etc., how do I calculate the efficiency of each route with distance, time, and cost criteria?

Once I've done this, how do I use my calculations (distance with time and cost fuel usage) in a genetic algorithm to find the optimum route?

Comment: How does this differ from the [Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem?

Comment: I think it's like a Travelling Salesman Problem sir. Sorry, I am just starting to learn about GA and I have a little confusion about the implementation in real problem. I have read about TSP too before, and if I'm not wrong TSP can be solved using another algorithm too. So, to clarify my question, I'm using genetic algorithm tag. Thanks

Comment: define "optimum"... Based on that you can calculate a value for each potential leg of the trip and let loose the traveling salesman problem...

Comment: I clarified the question by breaking it up along the lines of the answer, and wonder if it can be reopened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu The question does not show much effort on the part of the asker. If it said "here is my GA so far, but I am not sure how to get this one part to work" that would be acceptable. However, it reads to me as "I probably do not understand GAs and want someone to tell me everything."

Comment: @Snowman: Fair enough.

Comment: I apologize about my questions and my bad english. My problem is I have confused on how to find optimum route that not just a shortest way but with less cost and effective too. I have read some example but they just use distance to find/calculate the optimum route. But, david.pfx answers has made me more clear about how should I do to resolve this problem. I would like to thank to @Tom Au for editing my questions so it looks more clearer now and thanks to all people who contribute in my questions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a genetic algorithm you need chromosomes and a fitness function.

The chromosomes represent choices of route. Looks like 5 chromosomes, one for each city in order, but there could be a smarter way.

The fitness function is calculated from the chosen route. Score higher for visiting more cities and for shorter distance and lower cost of the chosen route.

The feed it in and stand back. You should get an optimal answer eventually.

Comment: Thank you the answer sir. List of route by the distance and include the costs and time in the fitness function?

Comment: Correct. Fitness function returns an overall score which chooses between organisms, each of which has a different route. Best route eventually wins.